# How to capture the action about starting dragging a window and releasing the capture of a window?

Tags: windows

When cursor honver over the title zone (HTCAPTION),press left mouse button, then you can drag a window and move it. When you release the left mouse button , you can stop this dragging action. When you move a window , it triggered the message WM_MOVE. When release the mouse button , I don't know which message should be handled for catching this action.

What I'm doing is when you drag a window(let's say window A) into another window's area(window B), make window A a child window of window B, when drag window A out of window B's area , make window A a WS_POPUP window, without WS_CHILD style.

I handled message WM_MOVE and WM_CAPTURECHANGED( I don't think it's the right one).
In WM_CAPTURECHANGED , I found something wired. The API `SetWindowPos` seemed not work well. To be percise, the 3rd and the 4th parmater , specified the window's position not work.

```
    case WM_CAPTURECHANGED: {
        RECT rcc;
        GetClientRect(main,&rcc); 
        // here main is the handler of window B , hwnd is for window A,as referrence above.
        
        if(docker_mode==DOCKER_LEFT) { 
            // docker_mode is assigned by WM_MOVE message handler. recording which area window A was moved into.  
            
            if((WS_CHILD&GetWindowLongPtr(hwnd,GWL_STYLE))!=WS_CHILD) {
                SetWindowLongPtr(hwnd,GWL_STYLE,(~WS_POPUP)&(WS_CHILD|GetWindowLongPtr(hwnd,GWL_STYLE)));
                SetParent(hwnd,main);
            }

            //The following code not work. It should be moved into the left-top corner of window B, 
            //but NOT in fact. 
            SetWindowPos(hwnd,NULL,0,0,300,rcc.bottom-rcc.top,SWP_NOZORDER);
        }
        else {
            if((WS_CHILD&GetWindowLongPtr(hwnd,GWL_STYLE))==WS_CHILD) {
                SetWindowLongPtr(hwnd,GWL_STYLE,((~WS_CHILD)&GetWindowLongPtr(hwnd,GWL_STYLE))|WS_POPUP);
                SetParent(hwnd,NULL);
                SetWindowPos(hwnd,NULL,300,0,0,0,SWP_NOMOVE|SWP_NOSIZE|SWP_NOZORDER|SWP_FRAMECHANGED);
            }
        }
        
    } break;
```

`SetWindowLongPtr(...,GWL_STYLE,...)`  was called to set the window style . A top level has no WS_CHILD style, and the handle of parent window should be NULL , I use  `SetParent(hwnd,NULL)` to do this. A child window should have WS_CHILD style, and the parent window should be assigned.

I put a button into the window , and copy those code into the handle of button click event. When click the button it works well , change a popup window into a sub window , put the sub window into right position. `SetWindowPos` has no problem at all. I don't know why.

`SetWindowPos` is a very interesting API when working on WM_CAPTURECHANGED handler. What's wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I recall correctly, when the user drags a window, that window receives a sequence of messages like this:

1. WM_ENTERSIZEMOVE
2. WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING
3. WM_MOVING
4. WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED
5. WM_MOVE
6. WM_EXITSIZEMOVE

(There are other messages, too, but I don't think you need to worry about those.  There may be some final messages after WM_EXITSIZEMOVE with the final resting place for the window.)

The steps in the middle will happen repeatedly as the user drags the window.  (In the Old Days, only some of those middle steps would happen, and there may still be an option to cut down on the messages during the drag operation.)

You can try using Spy++ (included with Visual Studio) to confirm the above.

So you shouldn't need to deal with the mouse capture messages.  Have window A watch for WM_EXITSIZEMOVE.  At that point, window A can check its position to see if it overlaps the target window (B).  If it does overlap, then it should send a message to window B to initiate the docking operation.